# JCA Remote Queue Wildfly Artemis

Tags: ejb, wildfly, activemq-artemis, jca

I have EJB deployed on a WildFly 18 server. I want to send message to a queue deployed on a remote WildFly 18 server (through ActiveMQ Artemis). Is that possible using injection and JCA and a `poole-connection-factory`?

Connection factory and queue are configured in the remote Wildfly as below:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:8.0">
   ...
   <pooled-connection-factory name="remote-artemis" entries="java:/jms/remoteCF" connectors="remote-http-connector"/>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

On the remote server, the queue is configured as below:

```xml
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging-activemq:8.0">
   ...
   <jms-queue name="WildFlyCookbookQueue" entries="java:/jms/queue/test java:jboss/exported/jms/queue/test"/>
   ...
</subsystem>
```

UPDATE

Here is my EJB trying to send message to the remote Artermis (inside remote wildfly):

```
@Stateless
public class MessageSender {

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("java:/jms/remoteCF")
    @JMSPasswordCredential(userName = "jmsuser", password = "jmsuser2020")
    private JMSContext context;
    @Resource(lookup = "java:/jms/queue/test")
    private Queue queue;

    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        context.createProducer().send(queue, message);
    }
}
```

When I try to deploy the war containing this EJB, I get the error saying that the queue does not exist.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible to inject a JCA-based `pooled-connection-factory` into your EJB running on WildFly 18 and send a JMS message to a remote WildFly server.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you please share documentation or resources I can read and follow to do so. I've updated my question with the EJB code.